# Jupyter Notebook Port binding issue on window server 2016

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, windows-server

I am trying to run jupyter notebook on windows server 2016 which is running on a server but due to server policies jupyter can not port bind to 8888 or any other ports that I give in the --port parameter.
I did netstat -an and saw some ports that were listening and tried to start jupyter on that port but still I am not able to acess jupyter. In short jupyter is not able to port bind.
I also installed vscode on the system and it was not able to connect to the kernel, I get the error:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Unable to start Kernel 'Python 3.11.5' due to a timeout waiting for the ports to get used.
```

is there a way I can get jupyter running either locally or inside vscode?

I tried nginx server but that also requires jupyter to be running and listening on a port.
vscode also didn't work.

I can see that the following ports are getting assigned when trying to launch the kernel. is there a way to mention these ports manually?

```
Process Execution: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m ipykernel_launcher --ip=127.0.0.1 --stdin=9008 --control=9006 --hb=9005 --Session.signature_scheme="hmac-sha256" --Session.key=b"30c29b5e-5c69-490b-9dd7-8b16892baf81" --shell=9007 --transport="tcp" --iopub=9009 --f=~\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-v2-5264xvhYGIzVxjYL.json
```

Comment: Are you using anaconda, which includes jupyter. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) is some additional information.

Comment: no I just installed it with pip

Comment: Try using anaconda.